# set a start and stop of getting div content from a page using PHP

Tags: php, html

file.html

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="ac"> ssssssssss </div>
    <div class="aa"> hhhhhhh </div>
    <p> dddd </p>
    <p class="ss">dddddddd </p>
    <span> ssssssss </span>
    <div class="sa"> <p> sss </p></div>
    <div class="ssa"> <p> sss </p></div>
    <div class="sa"> <span> sss </span></div>

    <!-- stop all if it comes to this div dont show anything under -->
    <div class="stop-here"> </div>
    <div class="sssa"> <p> sss </p></div>
    <div class="ssssa"> <p> sss </p></div>

</div>
```

i have a file.html and i want to get all tags inside a div, and i want it to stop getting contents once it sees a div with class "stop-here"

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('file.htm');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelistfulldesc = $xpath->query( "//div[@class='a']" );

foreach ($nodelistfulldesc as $fdn)
{
    $m .= $fdn->nodeValue;
}
```

this is the php am using to get all content, but cant stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such xpath to take all nodes in `div[@class='a']` before `div[@class="stop-here"]`

```
`//div[@class='a']/*[following::div[@class="stop-here"]]`
```

**update** it works very easy

`div[@class='a']/*` takes all children of the node

`[following::div[@class="stop-here"]]` selects among them those for which `div[@class="stop-here"]` is ahead

Comment: @ChrysUgwu i've written some words